# plot components of a vector separately in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python list of 3-dimensional numpy vectors, which can be created as follows:

```
import numpy as np
x = list()
for i in range(10):
    x.append(np.random.rand(3))
```

Now, I want to plot the x, y and z values of this vector collection in a matplotlib plot on the same plot with different colors. So, I want to create 3 graphs, one for each dimension, where the curves show how the signal evolves along each of these dimensions.

Comment: why the -ve votes? A comment would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trivial:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x)
plt.legend(['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

Comment: Thanks. New to this plotting business!